# what is a clean way of requiring external library inside a PHP class?

Tags: php, oop

I would like to use this hash library for hashing user passwords in my Auth class -

https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

So I can do:  `$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);` in `php < 5.5`

Would it be clean to include this functions file in the constructor? Or should I simply include it outside the class? What would be the benefit of one or the other?

```
require_once 'lib/password.php';

class Auth {}
```

or

```
class Auth
{
    function __construct()
    {
        require_once 'lib/password.php';
    }
}
```

I believe putting it under constructor would make it more like a dependency for the class. And others will be able to understand better?

Comment: Include it outside your own class like you have done in your first example..

Comment: @Hardy may I ask, why?

Comment: That is most simple way to do it and you can see all required classes top of your files. It depends of your needs. If you have some conditional includes, then you should do it in your other class.

Comment: Btw, password.php doesn't contain class, but set of functions procedural. Otherwise I would use to extend my Auth, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use autoloading in your project. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

It is the fastest and the most "clean" thing to do. All php framework use it.

Comment: I'm using autoloading for the class itself.

Comment: Great! Use it for library too!:) You could rewrite a bit the code of the lib to add 2 classes, instead of namespaces(i rly don't see point there) and you could use autoloading for them too, since you already had one set-up.

Comment: Or maybe I rewrite it and use it to extend auth class? will it be more logical this way?

Comment: I don't think it's logical. Authorization is not a child of HASH PASSWORDS in any way and HASH PASSWORDS should not be a child of Authorization. I would make a class with static methods and call like this: Passwords::hashPassword();

Answer (score 0):

I would do the first one. That way it is required even if the object is not instantiated, in case you would use it without instantiating the object. Then that makes the Auth class pointless unless you plan to add more.

Comment: Auth class contains whole lot more, I've reproduced a stripped down version here.